# Excel WebApi Odata Authentication with Organisational Account

Tags: excel, azure, authentication, odata

I have created an OData Service using .Net 6 / OData 8 and am trying to authenticate using Organisational Account in Excel. I can test the authentication sucesfully in Postman and also in my web App that uses the authenticated service.

However, if I try and create an OData Feed in Excel and authenticate using [Organisational Account], I get an error "We were unable to connect because this credential type isn't supported for this resource.".

Microsoft seems to indicate that it is not supported to connect to "arbitrary" services per the following link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/odatafeed#authenticating-to-arbitrary-services

However, this is a pretty big limitation and I'm interested to know if anyone has been able to solve this problem yet.

[image]

I won't go into the configuration of my web api, suffice it to say that I have tried every possible combination of builder.Services.AddAuthentication()..... that I can find and they all seem to have a similar issue - ie. I can use the WebApi for everything that I need it for - except Excel.

A quick Google search gets many, many hits (and I think that I have read them all - ..... twice), but try as I might I haven't yet found one that has an answer that works.

The following link showed some promise, which indicated it might be possible to change the audiencce, but I could not make it work.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-odata-feed-web-api-authentication-setup-with-azure-ad/

I did find another promising link that I can't seem to find again that indicated we could add the Office 365 Client Id to the list of Authorised Client Applications under Expose an Api of the app registration in Azure AD B2C.  I did that, with not success.

I'm really at my wits end on this and have been trying to get a solution on and off the last couple of weeks. Would really appreciate any help from others who might have tried and succeeded at this.

Comment: I haven't had any hits on this question as yet.  Would really appreciate it if anyone has solved the problem.   Here is a link to another SO post that gets closer than any others that I have seen, but still did not solve it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64602313/connecting-excel-to-oauth-api-on-azure/73244286#73244286

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirming that I have now worked out how to do this and have posted the solution to the following SO thread.  [connecting-excel-to-oauth-api-on-azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64602313/connecting-excel-to-oauth-api-on-azure/73244286#73244286)

There are a number of steps to the solutions, so won't attempt to summarise them here.